# Wordpress- Get custom post type associated with a custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-post-type

According to the WordPress Codex, the [`get_post_types()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) function has a 'taxonomies' parameter, but there is no explanation of exactly how it works.

```
$post_args = array(
            'public'   => true,
            'taxonomies' => 'genre',
            'show_ui' => true
            ); 

$post_types = get_post_types($post_args);
```

This above code doesn't return anything even though genre is a taxonomy that is registered to the 'book' post type.

If i have a custom post type of 'books' with some custom taxonomies of say, 'author' and 'genre'... I'd like to use `get_post_type()` to return the post type associated with 'genre'... obviously 'books'.  I'm trying to make something that will help set the `post_type` parameter in `get_posts()`.. since that only searches posts by default and not custom post types.  Obviously I could just set the `post_type` parameter, but I want to make it forward compatible with any future post types I might use in my different themes.

Answer (score 8):

Although I'm a bit late to the party on this one:

`taxonomies` isn't a valid argument for [`get_post_types()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types), so at best it will simply ignore the argument and return a list of all registered post types.

Probably your best bet is the [`get_taxonomy()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomy) object:

```
$currentTaxonomy = get_query_var('taxonomy');

//  Or: $currentTaxonomy = 'genre';

if ($currentTaxonomy) {
    $taxObject = get_taxonomy($currentTaxonomy);
    $postTypeArray = $taxObject->object_type;
}
```

This will give you an array of all post types that taxonomy is registered to.

Comment: Cool. I honestly have no idea what I was even trying to do here, but you never know who will find the post in the future. I've googled things years later and ended up finding my own posts!

Comment: @helgatheviking I do exactly the same thing, so this is kind of for my own reference as well. I've even googled a question and ended up on my own blog post before. All of this points to an insidious plot by the internet to rob me of my short-term memory. DAMN YOU INTERILLUMINATI.

Comment: Short-term memory? What is that?  As I said, I have no idea what I was originally trying to do, but this does answer the question as phrased in the title.

Comment: Where this is useful is when you want to display both the post type name and the taxonomy term on a taxonomy template page, eg: Books: Non-Fiction. This is trivial to do with `get_queried_object` but not so simple on a taxonomy term template

Answer (score 0):

Might want to use a combination of both: get_posts() and then pass in your post_type. Something like below might help get you started.

```
$post_types = get_post_types();
    if ( is_category() || is_tag()) {

        $post_type = get_query_var('article');

        if ( $post_type )
            $post_type = $post_type;
        else
            $post_type = $post_types;

        $query->set('post_type', $post_type);

    return $query;
    }
}
```

You would NOT want to use is_category and is_tag, you would use something like is_in_taxonomy(). What exactly are you trying to do? I think you're trying to do the same thing as me which is...

on archive page for custom post type use a custom loop for ALL taxonomies of certain custom post type. like the following:

```
taxonomy-[MY-CPT].php
```

vs.

```
taxonomy-[MY-CUSTOM-TAXONOMY].php
```

I'm actually trying to do the same as we speak, I'll let you know what I come up with.

NOTE there I just made up the is_in_taxonomy()